# Retrieve the "relevant tokens" with a BERT model (already fine-tuned)

Tags: keyword, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, attention-model

I already fine-tuned a BERT model ( with the huggingface library) for a classification task to predict a post category in two types (1 and 0, for example). But, I would need to retrieve the "relevant tokens" for the documents that are predicted as category 1 (for example). I know that I can use the traditional TF-IDF approach once I have all the posts labeled as 1 (for example) with my BERT model. But I have the following question:
is it possible to do the same task with the architecture of the fine-tunned BERT model? I mean, access to the last layer of the encoder (the prediction layer), and with the attention mechanism, get the "relevant" tokens that make that te prediction are 1 (for example)?
Is it possible to do that? Does someone know a tutorial o something similar?

Comment: You might want to get the self-attention matrices and find out what tokens contributed the most to the `CLS` token

Comment: Thank you for the response. I need to do that for the 12 heads of the encoder and find out what tokens contributed more to [CLS] in each one.

Answer (score 2):

With transformer models, you can perform some explainability analysis, which is probably what you want. I would recommend looking at the transformer section of [SHAP](https://github.com/slundberg/shap#natural-language-example-transformers). You just have to wrap your model in the SHAP explainer, like this:

```py
import shap
explainer = shap.Explainer(model)
```

There is another option if you have labels on which tokens are relevant, namely training a token classification model. But that would require retraining and labels for each token.